# jQuery function parameters to set SRC for image

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set SRC from parameters for large number of images?

I have 5 links like

```
<span onclick="showim('http://www.iiacanadanationalconference.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/test.jpg');">Show Image 1</span>
<span onclick="showim('img2.jpg');">Show Image 2</span>
<span onclick="showim('img3.jpg');">Show Image 3</span>
<span onclick="showim('img4.jpg');">Show Image 4</span>
<span onclick="showim('img5.jpg');">Show Image 5</span>
```

Only one image placeholder

```
<img src="" id="implace" width="100" />
```

And, JS code like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(function showim(imid) {
         var src = $("implace").attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + imid;
         $("#implace").attr("src", src);
     });
});
```

How can I make this code work? Can't understand why it's not working. Thanks

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/yessx/

Comment: Instead of changing the src, why not hide/show images? Then you won't have to wait to load the images.

Comment: Selector would be `#implace` not just `implace`.

Comment: @zaquest - Thanks, but still not working, please check the jsfiddle link. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it from here: http://jsfiddle.net/52dY7/

Need to make the function global, and also make sure to use # to select IDs.

Sample JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.showim = function(src) {
        $("#imgLoader").attr("src", src);
    };
});
```

If you want to queue it until the image itself is loaded, check here for a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/52dY7/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $loader = $('#imgLoader');

    window.showim = function(src) {
        var $im = $('<img/>');
        $im.attr('src', src);

        $loader.addClass('loading');
        $im.one('load', function() {
            $loader.removeClass('loading').attr('src', src);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: There is no need to put the `showim` function inside `document.ready()` at all.  In fact, `document.ready()` isn't needed in this problem.  Just define the `showim` function in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks, simple and effective code. Another thanks for the jsfiddle. :)

Comment: Can you please give tell how to load Ajax Loader image while the actual image is loading? Because actual images are high quality images and talking a while to load, in the meanwhile I want to display ajax loader gif image to make people understand they need to wait. Thanks

Comment: Added - http://jsfiddle.net/52dY7/3/ for a quick example. Just use the .one('load') function on "fake" image.

Answer (score 3):

Put a class for each span, and add the attribute data:

```
    <span class="spanClick" data-image="http://www.iiacanadanationalconference.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/test.jpg">Show Image 1</span>
    <span class="spanClick" data-image="img2.jpg">Show Image 2</span>
    <span class="spanClick" data-image="img3.jpg">Show Image 3</span>
    <span class="spanClick" data-image="img4.jpg">Show Image 4</span>
    <span class="spanClick" data-image="img5.jpg">Show Image 5</span>
```

in your js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".spanClick").bind("click",function(){
      var src = $(this).data("image");

      $("#implace").attr("src",src);
  });
});
```

When you invoke your jquery file dont forget call the jquery-migrate file, cause the function "bind" dont work in all jquery versions

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off preloading the images into hidden img containers, then showing them when the user clicks on the span.

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

preload([
    'img/imageName.jpg',
    'img/anotherOne.jpg',
    'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
]);

function showim(imid) {
//where imid is now the array index
$("#implace").append(arrayOfImages[imid]);
}
```

Comment: True, but worrying need to change in many areas to add more number of images in the later stage. As of now, we have more than 50 to display.

Comment: You can code this generically and have it recursively load images... I don't see an issue.

Comment: I am using $.each() if you look closely, i'm passing in an ARRAY of strings (image hrefs).

Comment: Good solution for preloading, but it doesn't directly answer the OP?

Comment: +1 for the code, but yeah seems bit confusion as I am not good at arrays :p

Comment: Look at the link I posted; you're really not. Or I'm really tired. To be honest, I'm not quite sure which...

Comment: "$(arrayOfImages).each("